# Java administrator permission execution error

Tags: java

I want to run the virtual keyboard on Java, but I don't know how to correct it because I got an administrator permission execution error.

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class FileOpenTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
     try {
         new ProcessBuilder("osk").start(); 
  } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

}

Comment: Did you try to run the program as administrator? I.e. open a console window as administrator and run the program from there?

Answer (score 1):

the command `osk` needs administrator privilege. you need to run the java program as admin too.